# How to create a box having border top width more than content at different browser display size?

Tags: html, css

I have created a box which has different top width as below picture.
[image: When browser is full screen]
However, for some reason when I resize the browser to 50% the content's width overshoots the top border's width.

[image: When browser is resized to 50%]

I am achieving this effect through the following CSS code

```
p.header{
width: 72%;
margin: 0% 15%;
background-color: lightblue;
border-left: 4px solid darkblue;
margin-bottom: 0px;
text-decoration: underline;
padding-left: 4px;
}

ol{
    border: none;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-left: 4px solid darkblue;
    width: 68.7%;
    margin: 0% 15%;
    padding-top: 10px; 
}
```

To overcome this, I have tried setting the border-top-width but it gives a skew sort of effect. 
I have also searched SO but to no avail.

Any help on how to achieve this even when the browser is resized, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the top border to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior happens because of the `box-sizing` of the elements. The margin percentage is a percentage of the width of the element, not the width of the page.

Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to both your `p` and `ol`